# What is the probability of a sudden reversal of the second law of thermodynamics?

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics

Some time ago I was listening to a lecture by High Ross (https://youtu.be/dsbj7EN1Uzs) and he mentioned how someone could instantaneously freeze to death by a sudden reversal of the second law of thermodynamics. The probability that hecame up with was 1 in 10^80. It is an interesting statistic, but does anyone have an idea of how he calculated this?

Here's his original comment:
"...at the University of British Columbia our physics professor had given us the assignment to calculate the probability that one of us students in the class would be killed by a sudden reversal of the second law of thermodynamics. It was a class in statistical mechanics. And I can tell you the probability is very tiny, but he wanted us to calculate what that probability was ... in this auditorium here we have quadrillions of air molecules. The physicists here in the audience will tell you that those air molecules are all at different temperatures. For example, within this room there are trillions of air molecules that are below the freezing point of water. And so there's a tiny statistical probability that those trillions of air molecules below the freezing point of water will within the next five seconds wander in the vacinity of where this young lady is sitting and freeze her to death."

Comment: The original comment you quote is wrong in so far, as that no single molecule in the air has a well defined temperature other than the temperature of the air in the room. The temperature of a single particle is only well-defined if it is coupled to a thermal bath, and then it has the temperature of that bath (by definition). So it does not make sense to speak of some molecule in the air being cold.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0417